# Melhor forma no Firebird, tendo segurança e leveza

Tags: delphi, firebird, trigger

Estou desenvolvendo um software em **Delphi**, utilizando **Firebird**. Minha meta e ter um software leve, rápido, mas, que tenha segurança, quanto a erros, corrupção no banco, resistir até onde der aos travamento do Windows, etc...

Considerando dados de uma tabela pai **TB_CAIXA**, para inserir dados numa tabela filha **TB_VENDAS**, para impedir que a venda seja gravada 
quando o status do **CAIXA** for **FECHADO (F)**, faço na **TB_VENDAS** um campo ComputedBy, checando o Status do caixa atual, e também um CHECK, comparando isto e, se for **ABERTO (A)**, deixo gravar. Parece eficiente, funciona.

Talvez, usar 6 campos *ComputedBy* só na **TB_VENDAS** seja má ideia, pois terá muitos dados.

Posso fazer a mesma coisa usando uma Trigger. Ok, se ela falhar, algum erro, deixar passar, vai lá o dado incorreto para a tabela. O Objetivo é não permitir a gravação incorreta e, manter a segurança e leveza no aplicativo.

Gostaria de ter alguns caminhos a seguir, para compreender melhor se é seguro neste caso, ou principalmente mais eficiente, usar apenas uma Trigger para validar isto?

Comment: Quando fala em Delphi e associa 'manter a segurança e leveza no aplicativo', a melhor opção é deixar o Banco de Dados resolver. No caso 'Posso fazer a mesma coisa usando uma Trigger.' é o caminho. Isto é, minha opinião.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De modo geral isso se trata da [regra de negócio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regras_de_neg%C3%B3cio) de sua aplicação.
Quanto a [tolerância a falhas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toler%C3%A2ncia_a_falhas) isso é muito relativo, pois há [falhas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tratamento_de_exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o) que é melhor que o sistema pare por completo do que continuar trabalhando sem algumas garantias.

Apesar do Firebird suportar [ACID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) e [MVCC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controle_de_concorr%C3%AAncia_multivers%C3%A3o), em algumas circunstâncias o sistema pode passar por sérios problemas "imprevisíveis", como por exemplo uma falta de espaço em disco, disco corrompido ou queda de energia ambiente. Estas situações podem prejudicar severamente sua aplicação. Cada situação pode ser monitorada e tratada, porém, para absolutamente tudo há um custo envolvido, podendo ser financeiro ou de processamento, cabe a você definir o quanto quer investir e o quanto cada investimento agrega valor ao seu software. Por exemplo, você poderia impedir que seu software abrisse após uma queda de energia até que uma análise no banco de dados determinasse se houve danos, porém, seus usuários/clientes podem ficar sem sistema por quanto tempo? seus usuários/clientes estão dispostos a utilizar medidas protetivas com nobreak para reduzir a ocorrência desse evento? prover uma recuperação segura e inteligente é algo que você consegue "vender"? seus concorrentes oferecem algo parecido que justifique que você tenha algo semelhante? Dependendo de suas (e/ou de seus usuários/clientes) necessidades talvez você deva analisar algumas soluções pagas, como SQL Server ou Oracle, por exemplo.

Vale ressaltar que o sistema operacional tem pouco ou nenhum impacto em relação aos problemas que podem ocorrer com o armazenamento dos dados ou a consistência das transações.

---

Voltando a regra de negócio, você pode optar por duas formas distintas com vantagens e desvantagens:

**Regras de negócio no Banco de Dados**

Você terá à disposição todo o poder do banco de dados que deseja utilizar, então poderá trabalhar com instruções [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) (DML, DDL, DCL, TCL...) para formar a regra da maneira que desejar. Isso inclui a implementação de triggers, procedures e/ou functions para resolver praticamente todas as suas necessidades.

**Vantagem**

- Extremamente seguro, pois o ACID e MVCC garantem a consistência de todas as transações;

**Desvantagem**

- Dependência absoluta de um determinado [SGDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados) (no seu caso, o Firebird). Isso pode não ser tratado como desvantagem, mas é importante estar ciente de que uma migração é bastante trabalhosa;
- Dificuldade para atualização do ambiente de produção com o ambiente em produção. Algumas operações não podem ser executadas se houver usuários conectados;
- Custo de armazenamento e processamento para servidor de banco de dados pode ser bem mais alto;
- Dependendo da complexidade poderá exigir pessoas experientes para lidar com determinados problemas;

---

**Regras de negócio na aplicação ([ORM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeamento_objeto-relacional))**

Utilizando uma solução ORM você pode colocar em sua aplicação tudo que deveria colocar no banco de dados, deixando este apenas para armazenar os dados já processados. Isso lhe dá um maior poder de controle sobre as informações, como gravar logs de auditoria antes de processar os dados recebidos, por exemplo.

**Vantagem:**

- Você pode permitir que seus clientes escolham (limitado por sua solução ORM) o banco de dados que deseja utilizar, inclusive mais de um simultaneamente;
- Você pode ligar/desligar regras de modo mais rápido e seguro;
- A atualização das regras fica condicionada ao update da aplicação ou módulo e pode ocorrer enquanto todos os usuários/clientes estão conectados;
- As regras podem ser modularizadas, sendo distribuídas e atualizadas conforme a necessidade do ambiente;
- É mais barato subir múltiplas instâncias da aplicação em múltiplas máquinas virtuais ou contêineres;

**Desvantagem**

- Dependendo da solução que adotar (ou ter criado a sua) pode ser muito limitante em termos de implementação. Por exemplo, você pode desejar utilizar um DB que ainda não é suportado;
- Você pode ter dificuldade para utilizar recursos avançados de alguns banco de dados, como o Full Text Search ou campos/documentos Json, por exemplo;
- É mais comum ocorrer problemas em soluções ORM do que em SGDB, e acredito que isso esteja ligado ao custo de engenharia e testes exaustivos. Note que para cada atualização de um SGDB há muito mais em soluções ORM;

---

Certamente há muito mais vantagens e desvantagens em cada um dos métodos. Você também pode mesclar as duas soluções, como criar determinadas triggers para determinados trabalhos no banco de dados e deixar as regras mais complexas e dinâmicas para a aplicação.

Tenha muito cuidado ao permitir que o sistema continue operando mesmo após ter detectado que há um problema, principalmente na camada de persistência dos dados.